# Property 'match' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I have recently converted a ReactJs project from ES6 JavaScript to TypeScript and had a wave of errors that I had to work through. One of the final errors that occurs and I cannot seem to find a fix for it for the section of code

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { pokemonIndex } = this.props.match.params;

    // Urls for pokemon information
    const pokemonUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`;
    const pokemonSpeciesUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${pokemonIndex}/`;

    // Get Pokemon Information
    const pokemonRes = await axios.get(pokemonUrl);

    const name = pokemonRes.data.name;
    const imageUrl = pokemonRes.data.sprites.front_default;

    let { hp, attack, defense, speed, specialAttack, specialDefense }: any = "";

    pokemonRes.data.stats.map(
      (stat: { [x: string]: any; stat: { name: any } }) => {
        switch (stat.stat.name) {
          case "hp":
            hp = stat["base_stat"];
            break;
          case "attack":
            attack = stat["base_stat"];
            break;
          case "defense":
            defense = stat["base_stat"];
            break;
          case "speed":
            speed = stat["base_stat"];
            break;
          case "special-attack":
            specialAttack = stat["base_stat"];
            break;
          case "special-defense":
            specialDefense = stat["base_stat"];
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    );
```

And more specifically on the line

```
const { pokemonIndex } = this.props.match.params;
```

What is the reason for this?

----------------EDIT----------------------------------

The code below is that of my App.tsx with the routing I've used

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./components/layout/NavBar";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import Dashboard from "./components/layout/Dashboard";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Pokemon from "./components/pokemon/Pokemon";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super({});
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <div className="container">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
              <Route exact path="/pokemon/:pokemonIndex" component={Pokemon} />
              <Dashboard />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Seems that it tries to get pokemonIndex value out of React Routing Params. And later this pokemonIndex is used to build new URLs as seen in source code you provide.

Comment: @SergeyM What do you mean by this? am I supposed to use a TS routing param now?

Comment: @SergeyM I have edited my question to show my routing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561848/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-readonly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type TRouteParams = {
    pokemonIndex: string; // since it route params
}
```

Then you can use this type for `RouteComponentProps` interface which stands for `this.props.match.params`

```
interface IPokemonPageProps extends RouteComponentProps<TRouteParams>, React.Props<TRouteParams> {
    ....
}
```

Now you should be able to access you prop like this:

```
const { pokemonIndex } = this.props.match.params;
```