# React Redux dispatch on componentDidMount -> property does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm working on my first project using React + Redux and am encountering few issues when I try to dispatch a function in the componentDidMount part. I tried to follow the [Reddit API example](https://redux.js.org/advanced/example-reddit-api) project in the docs but as they use JavaScript and I'm using TypeScript not quite everything is the same.

This is the React component where I'm trying to achieve this:

```
export class EducationComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch, getUser } = this.props;
        dispatch(getUser());
    }
    public render() {
        return (
            <Content className="component">
                <Demo/>
            </Content>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
    const { isLoaded, isFetching, user } = state.userProfile;
    return {
        user,
        isFetching,
        isLoaded
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EducationComponent)
export const Education = (EducationComponent);
```

I'm receiving following error in the `const { dispatch, getUser } = this.props;` line:

```
Error:(16, 17) TS2339: Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
Error:(16, 27) TS2339: Property 'getUser' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
```

The project can be found here if there are any uncertainties: https://github.com/jLemmings/GoCVFrontend

Is this the right way to get this done or are there better options?

Thanks

EDIT with current state:

```
const {Content} = Layout;

export class EducationComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.userAction();
    }
    public render() {
        return (
            <Content className="component">
                <Demo/>
            </Content>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
    userAction: action.getUser,
}, dispatch);

function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
    const { isLoaded, isFetching, user } = state.userProfile;
    return {
        user,
        isFetching,
        isLoaded
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EducationComponent)
```

FINAL EDIT (got it working):

```
interface MyProps {
    getUser: () => void
}

interface MyState {
    userAction: ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction>
}

export class EducationComponent extends Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    static defaultProps = {getUser: undefined};

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getUser()
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <Content className="component">
                <Demo/>
            </Content>
        );
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, any>, ownProps: MyProps) => {
    return {
        getUser: () => {
            dispatch(getUser());
        }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
    const {isLoaded, isFetching, user} = state.userProfile;
    return {
        user,
        isFetching,
        isLoaded
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EducationComponent)
```

Comment: These are typescript errors.

Comment: Hi, try this repository, [https://github.com/senthilmca90/mern-crud](https://github.com/senthilmca90/mern-crud). you try the `client` folder react code.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your project, you are importing the component like this :

```
import {Education} from "../pages/Public/Education";
```

This will import the non connected component that's why you don't have access to dispatch.

You should import the default connected component :

```
import Education from "../pages/Public/Education";
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've added the current state of the code as it still isn't working. I just can't access the userAction in the props...

Comment: Are you doing `import {EducationComponent}` , or `import EducationComponent ` ?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I followed your suggestion to import it like this: `import EducationComponent`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.getUser();
}

// mapStateToProps

mapDispatchToProps = (state) => {
   getUser: () => dispatch(getUser()); //Don't forget to import getUser from your action creator
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EducationComponent)
export const Education = (EducationComponent); // Delete this line no need for this because you're already exporting it as default
```

Reference: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#arguments

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've added the current state of the code as it still isn't working. I just can't access the userAction in the props...

Comment: You can try writing your mapDispatchToProps like this

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching actions returned by action creators
    increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
    decrement: () => dispatch(decrement()),
    reset: () => dispatch(reset())
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but it didn't work. I'm working with TypeScript and not JavaScript so it's a bit harder to follow your guidelines...

Comment: @In0cenT This might solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561848/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-readonly since TS doesn't know the type of dispatch

Answer (score 0):

Do you bind the dispatch method using `mapDispatchToProps`?