# React Fabric Ui Panel can't close

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric-react

I have an Sharepoint app. By clicking on a command list button I open a panel.

But when I try to close the panel I get a error saying that my _renderPanelComponent function is not a function and when trying to log it from _dismissPanel() it I get that it is undefined. But I can call it from _showPanel().

By logging from _dismissPanel() I now that I get back here after clicking close and triggered _onCancel() but I'm not sure why my _renderPanelComponent gets undefined and thats my question.

This is what the code looks like

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseListViewCommandSet,
  Command,
  IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters,
  IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters
} from '@microsoft/sp-listview-extensibility';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { assign } from '@uifabric/utilities';
import MainPanel, { IMainPanelProps } from '../MainPanel';

export interface ICreditInfoCommandSetProperties {
  sampleTextOne: string;
  sampleTextTwo: string;
  context:object;
}

export default class CreditInfoCommandSet extends BaseListViewCommandSet<ICreditInfoCommandSetProperties> {

  private panelPlaceHolder: HTMLDivElement = null;

  public _renderPanelComponent(props: any) {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMainPanelProps> = React.createElement(MainPanel, assign({
      isOpen: false,
      onClose: null,
      context: this.context
    }, props));
    ReactDom.render(element, this.panelPlaceHolder);
  }
  
  private _showPanel() {
    this._renderPanelComponent({
      isOpen: true,
      onClose: this._dismissPanel,
      context: this.context
    });
  }
  
  private _dismissPanel() {
    console.log(typeof(this._renderPanelComponent))
    this._renderPanelComponent({ isOpen: false});
  }

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'Initialized CreditInfoCommandSet');
    this.panelPlaceHolder = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  @override
  public onListViewUpdated(event: IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters): void {
    
  }

  @override
  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'COMMAND_2':
        this._showPanel();
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown command');
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what my panel looks like

```
import * as React from 'react';
// Custom imports
import { Panel, PanelType , TextField, Checkbox, DefaultButton, PrimaryButton, Dropdown, IDropdownOption} from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import style from "./MainPanelStyle.module.scss";

export interface IMainPanelProps {
    onClose: () => void;
    isOpen: boolean;
}

export interface IMainPanelState {}

export default class MainPanel extends React.Component<IMainPanelProps, IMainPanelState> {

    constructor(props: IMainPanelProps, state: IMainPanelState) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {}

private _onCancel = () => {
        this.props.onClose();
}


public render(): React.ReactElement<IMainPanelProps> {
        return (
            <div>

                <Panel isLightDismiss={true} isOpen={this.props.isOpen} type={PanelType.medium} onDismiss={this.props.onClose}>

 <DefaultButton className={style.closeButton} text="Close" onClick={this._onCancel}/>

                 </Panel>
                  </div>
         );
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too. Changing this

`private _dismissPanel() {`

to

`private _dismissPanel = () =>{`

Got this working for me, as it binds the method to the scope of its class so `this` can be properly resolved. I realize this is an old post but just in case any one else runs into this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it was an important missing piece for me.

For anyone using TypeScript and struggling to use state to show and hide their react component as per the many examples, make sure your class includes STATE and not just PROPS. The answer above does do but it caught me out.

See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561848/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-readonly