# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null when I add an interface to resolve Readonly property error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror

I have this:

```
interface State {
  backgroundColor: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
  errorOccured: boolean;
  acknowledgment: string;
}

export class GoodIntention extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    ...
    onClickOfAgreement = (policy: string) => () => {
        this.setState({backgroundColor: true});
        ...
    }
   
    render() {
        return(
            ...
            <table className={'checkbox-table ' + this.state.backgroundColor}>
                <label>
                    <input className="checkbox-round" type="checkbox" onClick={this.onClickOfAgreement(policy)}/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp; Agree and access my certificate and disc
                </label>
          </table>
          ...
}
```

When I run my application the browser gives this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'backgroundColor')

on line `<table className={'checkbox-table ' + this.state.backgroundColor}>`.

I added the `State` interface to resolve a `Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'` error based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561848/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-readonly). I seem to be missing something though. CAn anybody advise what that is?

Answer (score 0):

The setState is in the onClickOfAgreement function. backgroundColor doesn't exist until the first time the user clicks.

Comment: OK, makes sense. How do I resolve it though? Move the setState to some other location?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See, https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class