# Is it a bad practice to use state in a React component if the data will not change? Should I use a property on the class instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, reactive-programming

Say I have React component that renders a set of buttons,I store the information for the buttons in an object, with a label and a method to run when they are attached.

The buttons do not need to react to any changes, and will never change themselves.

Is it a bad practice to store the information for these buttons in the state? These are the current solutions I have come up with so far.

**1. Storing Buttons in State**

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      buttons: [
        {
          label: 'Save',
          method: this.save
        },
        {
          label: 'Edit',
          method: this.edit
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  // Class Methods
  // ...
  // End of Class Methods

  render() {
    <ButtonGroup buttons={this.state.buttons} />
  }
}
```

**2. Storing Buttons outside of React's State**

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.buttons = [
      {
        label: 'Save',
        method: this.save
      },
      {
        label: 'Edit',
        method: this.edit
      }
    ];
  }

  // Class Methods
  // ...
  // End of Class Methods

  render() {
    <ButtonGroup buttons={this.buttons} />
  }
}
```

**3. Using a Stateless Functional Component (applicable only if no class methods are needed and no other state is used)**

```
function save() {
  ...
}

function edit() {
  ...
}

const buttons = [
  {
    label: 'Save',
    method: save
  },
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    method: edit
  }
];

const Header = () => (<ButtonGroup buttons={buttons} />);
```

What the question really boils down to is:

- Is it a bad practice to store data in the state that will not change, and remain constant?
- Will using state for constants effect performance?
- Is there a reason to store data that won't change within the state, If I do have state elsewhere, is it easier to just use the state for everything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684481/is-the-constructor-still-needed-in-react-with-autobinding-and-property-initializ . No need of explicitly defining the constructor when you don't need props to initialize your component

Comment: 1 and 2 seem identical to me

Comment: Props is generally the easier way, in case you want to reuse your component at a later time. If you will always render the same "hardcoded" buttons, then why not simply leave them in the render method?

Comment: @stack26 I was under the impression that without transforming class properties, setting state explictly without defining the constructor will only work in the latest Chrome.

Comment: @Chris Aplogies, cocked up when formatting, replaced it now.

Comment: if Es6 is not supported in your browser, and you are not using babel-transpilers, then you class keyword itself will throw the error.

Comment: I think the problem is a component with this signature: `<ButtonGroup buttons={this.buttons} />`  I'd have something more like `<EditGroup saveLabel="Save" saveAction={this.save} editLabel="Edit" editAction={this.edit} />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick answers to your questions:

> Is it a bad practice to store data in the state that will not change, and remain constant?

Somewhat, yes. The state is meant to store the current "state" of your UI. If a specific UI component never changes it doesn't really make sense to talk about "states", because there is only one.

> Will using state for constants effect performance?

No.

> If there a reason to store data that won't change within the state, If I do have state elsewhere, is it easier to just use the state for everything?

There isn't really, but even if it was considered a valid practice, I would argue that you are sacrificing readability and structure in your code because you wouldn't be distinguishing between the *static* and *dynamic* stuff in your UI.

---

Based on the snippets provided, I would strongly suggest either `(2)` or `(3)`. I would consider both of these good practices depending on where you want to store the data (within or outside your component) and if flexibility is important.

Comment: How about just having the buttons as part of the children instead of the buttonGroup component

Comment: @Icepickle Sure, but I don't see how that would answer OP's question.

Comment: It would be an option how to promote re-usability for the OP that he might not have considered before?